# How do I fill() this shape?

Tags: java

```
    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
        
        AffineTransform gat = new AffineTransform();
        gat.translate(getWidth() / 2.0, getHeight() / 2.0);
        gat.scale(1.0, -1.0);
        g2d.transform(gat);
        
        QuadCurve2D q2d = new QuadCurve2D.Double(
                -220.0,   //Bottom x
                170.0,  //Bottom Y
                -115.0,   //Middle X
                330.0,  //Middle Y
                0.0,   //Top X
                200.0    //Top y
        );
                
        
        AffineTransform at = new AffineTransform();
        at.scale(scaleX, scaleY);
        scaleX += 0.01;
        scaleY += 0.01;
        Shape s = at.createTransformedShape(q2d);
        
        g2d.setPaint(Color.RED);
        g2d.fill(s);
        
        g2d.setStroke(new BasicStroke(3.0f));
        g2d.setPaint(Color.BLACK);
        g2d.draw(s);
        
        Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().sync();
```

When it runs only the outer heart fills. Which leaves a diamond shape unfilled in the middle. Any suggestions? On top of this any idea on how to make the heart grow and shrink? Theres 3 duplicate lines of this to complete a heart shape.

Comment: Could you add an image of what it draws so it is easier to visualize?

Comment: And a decent [mre]. Note that I would get most of that code *out* of the paintComponent method so that it is created once and only once. Use paintcomponent to draw it once the object has been created. Also, have you tried using a Path2D for this?

Comment: As @HovercraftFullOfEels says, if you put runnable code in your question people are much more likely to try it out themselves and help.

Comment: Changing scaleX and scaleY in a painting method is going to cause problems.  You do not control how often paintComponent is called;  it’s called by the system, in response to many different system events and user actions.  Moving, resizing, or deiconifying the window will usually trigger it.  Unlocking the screen may trigger it.  Even moving the mouse over the window may trigger it.  If you want to change how things are drawn, do it outside of a painting method.